# Why are men stronger than women?

Tags: evolution, human-genetics, sexual-selection

What are the evolutionary explanations for why women are physically weaker than men (on average), and is this difference adaptive? [See figure one here.](http://jap.physiology.org/content/83/5/1581)

I suppose that something puts pressure on men to be physically stronger than women, but I don't see what it can be. Why the discrepancy between the sexes?

Comment: You should clarify your question, and your reason for asking. I assume that you are asking about a difference in average physical strength of sexes (and evolutionary reasons for this), but the Q can be read in other ways as well. Also, differences in body size/strength between sexes is common in many animals (see [Sexual dimorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_dimorphism)), and this is usually not to "dominate women" but often (when males are larger/stronger) used in male-male competition.

Comment: For the record, I don't think the Q should be closed as opinion-based. As currently stated, I find it unclear with poor background, but there is a relevant Q on the evolution of sexual differences in humans hiding in there.

Comment: I agree.  this site is so steeped in the jargon of biology that it can't handle questions from the public.  [reopen]  The term they need to hear is 'sexual selection' which was broadly discussed by Darwin.  Its not entirely incumbent upon the question if the readers misunderstand.  Men and women are clear terms that specify human males and females. Fairly precise.

Answer (score 9):

> What are the evolutionary explanations for why women are weaker than men (on average), and is this difference adaptive?

All of the theories surrounding this fact are speculative; it would be difficult to prove "why" men are, on average, stronger than women.

One contributing theory is [Female-Choice](http://adarwinstudygroup.org/sexuality/female-choice/) - basically that women had (or has) the ability to be more selective when it comes to choosing a mate. Over time men will reflect the preferences of women (taller than them, stronger than them, facial hair qualities, etc.). This is superficially supported by casual studies like [this study from OkCupid](http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/your-looks-and-online-dating/) where the "attractiveness" curve for men is down-shifted, meaning women think the average man looks below average in attractiveness and implying those who are viewed as average ( *actually* the top 20% of men or so) would have better reproductive success. Men, in the same casual study, had a nearly perfect bell-curve associated the attractiveness of women, implying that men are excellent at deducing whether a women is below average in attractiveness, average, or above average in attractiveness.

Another contributing theory is [Male-Male Competition](http://adarwinstudygroup.org/sexuality/male-competition/). Basically men, at some point (and still might) compete with other men to win over women. The bigger, stronger man would presumably win in a fight and eliminate his competition - directly preventing the production of offspring by the weaker male. The male-male competition also holds true in a more speculative theory in that the winners of wars literally *raped* their way to reproductive success.

It is worth noting that men, on average, are only about [30-40% stronger than women](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8477683) due to the larger muscle fibers in men (as cross-sectional area determines muscle strength, not volume). With training the difference (kg for kg) [is reduced to 15-20%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_weightlifting).

Ultimately *why* women are weaker than men (or men are stronger than women - whichever way you prefer to put it) doesn't have a solid answer beyond "because the stronger, taller men have reproduced".

Comment: I find your first subanswer somewhat vague. The Q is probably asking if there are evolutionary reasons why men are on average psysically stronger than women (see [Sex differences in human physiology#strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_differences_in_human_physiology#Strength.2C_power_and_muscle_mass)). How strong we are in comparison to other animals isn't really relevant for this question. However, sex differences in species closely related to us is interesting to understand our evolutionary history.

Comment: Saying 'men have more capacity for strength', 'men never use it' is not relevant either. It still does not explain why both genders diverged, and men diverged to be stronger.

Comment: @QuoraFeans - Then ask your question again, and be more precise. You're asking why the genders diverged in capacity for muscle development, and I answered that the theories involve Female-Selection for stronger men and that men acted as the defenders/hunters. What type of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @MCM This is a good attempt at an answer. "The male-male competition also holds true in a more speculative theory in that the winners of wars literally raped their way to reproductive success." This is a rather grim prospect, but I would entirely believe it as a driving force in our selection. Is there any citation or study into this?

Comment: Moreover, the male-male competition and the success of the stronger man should lead to evolution of stronger humans (both men and women). If it has more effect on males then there is something that pertains to the activity of Y-chromosome. This would finally boil down to whether androgens have a positive role in promoting muscle development (more than estrogens).

Comment: @WYSIWYG Not necessarily, selective pressure on one sex does not have to have any effect on the other.

Comment: but can you explain WHY all of these possible reasons are sex-specific? Whether it be 'Female choice' or 'Male Male competition', why wasn't it the other way round, like 'Male Choice' or 'Female Female competition' ?

Comment: @user1993 - No, and I doubt anyone will ever confidently be able to do so. It could be due to a population bottleneck millions of years ago. It could be down to a few mutations on the Y chromosome. It could be deeply integrated with how we have young. Nobody really knows the 'why', only what's happened since.

Comment: @WYSIWYG As this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%27s_principle states(Bateman's principle), Can the reason be "Sperms are cheaper than eggs (ibid). So producing a strong male means they can protect the female and even if while protecting the female,the male by chance dies accidentally,the loss can be compensated by the long surving female who can be able to repopulate effectively with the lesser number of available males"? To conclude,I don't know the exact reason and asking can this be reason?